# Simplest way to perform multiple long running processes concurrently c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, parallel.foreach

I have a long running job I need to run once for each item in a collection.

I'd like to do these jobs concurrently, although the entire program can wait for all jobs to complete. (I may change that later, but for now, I'm keeping the problem simple)

Following some help already given, I've got the following pattern:

```
public static void DoWork()
{
    //Get a collection of items
    var items = GetMyItems();

}


private async void DoStuffWithItems(ICollection<MyItem> items)
{
    var tasks = items.Select (i => DoStuffWithItem(i));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private Task DoStuffWithItem(MyItem item)
{
    //LongRunningTask
    return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var returnObject = await LongRunningAsyncMethod(item);
            });
}
```

If I understand it right though, THIS does each task one at a time still - so pointless.

Someone suggested I used Parallel.ForEach in combination with async await - the Parallel-ForEach pattern is easy enough:

```
public static void DoWork()
{
    //Get a collection of items
    var items = GetMyItems();
    
    Parallel.ForEach(items, (item) =>
    {
        var returnObject = LongRunningMethod(item);
    }

}
```

Now if I understand THIS correctly, I'll kick off a separate thread for each item to do its thing, but while it is doing this, the main thread will wait

But what if I want the rest of the program to carry on while DoWork is waiting for the Parallel.ForEach to complete?

```
public static void DoWork()
{

//Get a collection of items
var items = GetMyItems();

DoINeedThisMethod(items);


}

private async void DoINeedThisMethod(ICollection<MyItem> items)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            DoStuffWithItems(items);
        });
    }

private async void DoStuffWithItems(ICollection<MyItem> items)
{
        var newobjs = new List<MyItem>();

            Parallel.ForEach(items, (item) =>
            {
                var bc = LongRunningAsyncMethod(item);
            });
}
```

It doesn't feel quite right - and I have an async void in there which isn't good practice. But am I along the right lines here?
If I understand correctly, in DoINeedThisMethod, I'm spinning up a new thread (via Task) to perform the Parallel.ForEach call, but the use of "wait" in there means that the main thread will now continue while the Parallel.ForEach completes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, your first assumption

> If I understand it right though, THIS does each task one at a time
> still

is wrong as can easily be proven:

```
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        async Task DoStuffWithItem(int i)
        {
            // long running task
            Console.WriteLine($"processing item {i} started");
            await Task.Delay(500);
            Console.WriteLine($"processing item {i} finished");
        }
        
        var items = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

        var tasks = items.Select(i => DoStuffWithItem(i)).ToList();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        Console.WriteLine("\nFinished");
    }
```

yields the following output:

```
processing item 1 started
processing item 2 started
processing item 3 started
processing item 2 finished
processing item 1 finished
processing item 3 finished

Finished
```

So the tasks are executed concurrently...

Note: as explained in a comment below, the 'ToList()' causes the Linq Query to be executed immediately (which starts the tasks immediately).
Without the 'ToList()', the tasks will only be started upon executing 'await Task.WhenAll(tasks)'

Comment: Sigh - I was so close then when I started today - but then went down a long rabbit hole :(

On my third point, presumably that will all hold up the Main thread while those tasks complete. If instead of Main() it was a done in
private static async Task MyBackgroundWorker() and I just called that method from a GUI, would the use of Task.WhenAll(tasks) inside it mean that the GUI wasn't waiting for all tasks to complete?

Comment: @tonydev314: I get the feeling you do not yet have a correct understanding of the difference between 'Task.Wait' and 'await':
If you await the execution of a Task, your code stops at that point (until the task stops running). However, the thread on which your code is running, is not blocked. In your example, the GUI-thread would still react to user- and system-events. 
A good introduction to Async..Await: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: One more thing to note: in the examples, you construct the 'tasks' instance using Linq (the 'Select' method). This has a side-effect: the Linq enumeration isn't executed until 'tasks' is evaluated. As a consequence, in the above sample the long running tasks will not be started until you reach the 'await Task.WhenAll(tasks)' statement.
If you want to start the tasks, execute some more stuff before waiting for the tasks to finish but (while they are running), you need to force execution of the Linq query (e.g. by calling 'ToList': var tasks = items.Select(i => DoStuffWithItem(i)).ToList();'

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed by @Johan, the calls to `DoStuffWithItem` *should* happen simultaneously.

This is because the method returns `Task`, which may be clearer if you elide the lambda expression, which is completely unnecessary:

```
var tasks = items.Select(DoStuffWithItem);
```

Also, you shouldn't use `Task.Run` in the implementation of `DoStuffWithItem`. If `LongRunningAsyncMethod` is truly asynchronous, it will release the thread whilst I/O occurs anyway, which in turn allows your `Select` to generate the tasks in parallel.

Using `Task.Run` simply adds unnecessary overhead through thread switching and allocation.

You should abandon the idea of combining `Parallel.ForEach` with `await`; they serve different purposes.

`Parallel` utilises multiple threads and is suited to CPU-bound work, whereas `async` releases threads whilst asynchronous work (I/O) happens.

You should stick to your `Select` / `WhenAll` version, but without the `Task.Run`, as long as `LongRunningAsyncMethod` is implemented asynchronously.

Comment: Yes - done that - the method called is marked async, but there's an issue with it. It seems that Await.When in the calling method, doesn't wait for the awaits in the long running task to complete - this is within the confines of a Test procedure. So the test completes and the final assertion fails. I presumed Wait bubbled? i.e. waited for all awaits down the callstack?

Comment: OK my bad - I was using await in the calling method, which is fine if THAT method is async, but in a test, I need to remove the await there.

Comment: @tonydev314 Why is that? Modern UT frameworks will invariably support async test methods.